# bootstrap bootslider layout issue caused by white space

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, slider

The problem is I am using BootSlider.js that I cam across online, and it does everything that i require it to, apart from one thing.  The actual slider set white-space:none on its main div.

So as you will see in the slider panels in the url above, I have text in each panel that needs to wrap.  This text is in a  tag.  If I set white-space: wrap on the SPAN in each panel, then you will see that the more wrapping text, the further away from the top each panel sits.

I have tried to see what the CSS problem is but am stuck - would be great if anyone could help?

It's using bootstrap 3 no option to use 4 sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this rules to `.index-inner1`

```
.index-inner1 {
    display:flex; /* add this line */
    flex-direction: column; /* add this line */

    padding: 8px !important;
    min-height: 290px !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! :) Only one more thing: that library is very old and it is based on a rule 'white-space:nowrap' that causes lot of additional problems (as you well understood). I suggest you, for the next site, to change it. There are many other carousel library works very well! ;)